# How can i send a http GET request with a variable that inc/decrease after link click with php

Tags: php, mysql, get

I have build a php page that queries a Mysqli database with a GET request.
One of the GET variables ( &day= ) queries the datas by date.  If day=0 it queries the actual date. If day = 1 it queries date-1, and so on.
This works fine with 2 buttons mixing javascript and php form + buttons. (code pasted somewhere and modified to my needs)

Today i added some "cosmectics" to my page. I added some folder like links.

I'm stucked in that i can't find how to change the day variable by clicking on the + and - html links...

[My page to be more clear...](http://www.egloff.eu/apaguard/apaguard_table.php)

The link code :
`echo "<li><a href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?rucher=".$rucher_nr."'><span>-</span></a></li>";`
Thanks,

Comment: Can you please paste your code here, so we can quickly find the problem?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Do you want me to post the full code ? It's about 200 lines of php..

Comment: Yeah come on, we are so exited!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a pure php solution using a session variable i'm incrementing ou decrementing through 2 links and a GET post.
I also modified my SQL query to query by DATE and not with the INTERVAL query.

Sorry for bandwidth...